# JSON array from JSON object is returning null

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to read JSON array

```
"connectTo":[   
    {
        "url": "wss://localhost/opt/siml"
    }   
],
```

from JSON string :

```
{

"cluster":{
    "enabled":"true",
    "clusterName":"cluster0",
    "simlURL":"wss://localhost:5443/opt/siml"
},

"simlFieldWatchUrl":"fieldwatchholder.jsp",

"persistFolder":"clusterconfig/concentratorBPersist",

"sslCrtFile":"clusterconfig/certDirB/siml.crt",
"sslKeyFile":"clusterconfig/certDirB/siml.key",

"SIMLID":"TestServerB",

"localWebProxyServer":"localhost",
"localWebProxyPort":8080,
"SIMLProxyPort":8400,
"SIMLWebPort":8300,

"turnOnExtraSIMLWebSocket":"false",

"autoPromoteNewConnectionsFromPurgatory":true,

"connectTo":[   
    {
        "url": "wss://localhost/opt/siml"
    }   
],

"tempLogins":[
    {
        "username":"root",
        "password":"root"
    }
]

}
```

My code to read url is:

```
JSONArray connectTo = (JSONArray) config.get("connectTo");
                System.out.println("Connect to : " + connectTo);
                for (Object o : connectTo) {
                    JSONObject connect = (JSONObject) o;
                    String url = (String) connect.get("url");
                    System.out.println(url);
                }
```

But **System.out.println("Connect to : " + connectTo);** this is returning 
**Connect to : []**

I read some old question but did not get satisfactory answer. Please Help. And thank you in advance :)

Comment: Is this string your whole json? Valid json must start with { or [.

Comment: This string is just  part of json i want to read. Whole json is big file.

Comment: Post Json with the proper format then we can help you extract the content

Comment: Hmm did you try convert to JSONObject instead of JSONArray?

Comment: Yes, I tried like  JSONObject connectTo = (JSONObject) config.get("connectTo"); 
but throwing casting exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just assume `config` is a JSONObject.

```
JSONArray connectTo = config.getJSONArray("connectTo");
```

`config.get()` returns an Object while `config.getJSONArray()` returns a `JSONArray`.

Comment: but same i said above for config.getJSONArray, it is showing cannot resolve method getJSONArray

Comment: What is the output of _System.out.println(config.toString());_?

Comment: {"cluster":{"simlURL":"wss:\/\/localhost:8200\/opt\/siml","clusterName":"cluster0","enabled":"true"},"tempLogins":[{"password":"root","username":"root"}],"autoPromoteNewConnectionsFromPurgatory":true,"turnOnExtraSIMLWebSocket":"false","SIMLWebPort":8200,"persistFolder":"clusterconfig\/concentratorAPersist","localWebProxyServer":"localhost","SIMLProxyPort":8100,"_sslDirectory":"clusterconfig\/certD","connectTo":[],"sslCrtFile":"clusterconfig\/certDirA\/siml.crt","localWebProxyPort":8080,"sslKeyFile":"clusterconfig\/certDirA\/siml.key","simlFieldWatchUrl":"fieldwatchholder.jsp"}

Comment: I ma sorry its messy but it is Json string

Comment: It looks like your "connectTo" IS actually empty. So there's nothing wrong with the code. And this JSON is completely different from the one in the question.

Comment: Ohh yeah i did not notice that. But I am not sure why it is not reading this. I don't understand it is reading "tempLogins":[{"password":"root","username":"root"}]  which is same as connectTo. Do you have any idea.?

Comment: Do you have the JSON stored in a file and read it from there? Or how do you even get this JSON?

Comment: JSONObject config = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(file));
file variable is path to json file.

Comment: Oh, I see. You're using _org.json.simple_ libraries not _org.json_. That's why _.getJSONArray_ doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
JSONArray connectTo =config.getJSONArray("connectTo");

                    System.out.println("Connect to : " + connectTo);
                    for (int i=0;i<connectTo.length();i++) 
    {
                        JSONObject connect = connectTo.getJSONObject(i);
                        String url = connect.get("url");
                        System.out.println(url);
                    }
```

Comment: for config.getJSONArray, it is showing cannot resolve method getJSONArray.

Comment: Where have you defined your config variable?

Comment: JSONObject config = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(file));
and file is path of json file.

Comment: @p05p JSONObject config = new JSONObject(new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader(file));

Comment: still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this, not sure if this helps:

```
var json = {
  "connectTo": [{
    "url": "wss://localhost/opt/siml"
  }]
};

for (var o = 0; o < json.connectTo.length; o++) {
  console.log(json.connectTo[o].url);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but for this i have to modify my json string. ?